The uid generator is giving negative value(-8201645565344219221) and using this implementation DefaultUidGenerator.java to generate unique id
The uid generator is giving negative value(-8201645565344219221) and using this implementation
https://github.com/baidu/uid-generator/blob/master/src/main/java/com/baidu/fsg/uid/impl/DefaultUidGenerator.java
to generate unique id but they were applied time only 8 years and 6 months after that generating minus value as uniqueId. Can you please me to resolve to get the positive uniqueId.
I need to get generate positive uniqueId using DefaultGenerator implementation.

The docs state "Supports about 8.7 years until to 2024-11-20 21:24:16".  However, the api supports setEpochStr which defaults to "2016-05-20" so try providing an epoch that suits your needs.

It's returned as long, which is a signed type. Why do you care it's negative?

If you want it as a (perhaps) more usable hex string, then you could do: String sUID = BigInteger.valueOf(uid).and(new BigInteger("FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF",16)).toString(16);

@g00se from the documentation, this unique id is specified as a 64-bit number with the highest bit (the sign bit) always 0. Therefore negative numbers, or numbers rendered as unsigned 64-bit decimal with the highest bit set to 1, are not compliant.

@k314159 OK. So that suggests the value -8201645565344219221 is wrong in that case

@g00se yes, that's due to a limitation as Computable explained in their comment above.

I'm wondering exactly how a negative value was obtained

@Computable, It's about support 8.6 years but is there possible to increase "date or it's support 100 years with generate positive UID. IF it is possible, provide the solution. I hope you understand.

For a 100-year span (regardless of epoch) you would need to use 32 timeBits (defaults to 28) and reduce workerBits (default 21) and seqBits (default 13) in some combination by a total of 4 bits.  There are setters for each of these properties.  The main README.md of that repo explains this very well.

As per calculate timeBits=32, workerBits=21 and seqBits=13 So total 66 Bits. It should not more than 64 bits. The total bits must be 64 -1.  Can you calculate timeBits=32, workerBits=21 and seqBits=13 So total 63 Bits. Based on combinations Can you tell me how many years it's should support?

The library you're using hasn't seen any updates since six years. Are you sure you want to continue using it? I would switch to a library that is still maintained....

@Computable, please calculate years based on given bits.

By my reckoning, 32 time bits would give you instants up to 2288-08-02T12:56:31Z

@g00se Can you please tell how did you calculate. And can you update timeBits, workerBits and seqBits combinations to support 100 year span. Thank you

@RajeshRudra You'll need 32 time bits AND a combination of workerBits and seqBits totaling 31 bits (e.g. 20+11). 2^32=4294967296 seconds which when divided by secs/year gives ~136 years of time span (any absolute date would require assuming epoch as stated). Again, all in the README docs referenced previously.

final Instant EPOCH_START = LocalDateTime.parse("2016-05-20T00:00:00.000").atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toInstant(); Instant maxInstant = EPOCH_START.plusSeconds((1L << 33) - 1); is what I looked at, but I'm not going to write your code for you

Easier: final Instant EPOCH_START = Instant.parse("2016-05-20T00:00:00.000Z");
